# Global locking for Striped lock from GUAVA library

Tags: java, concurrency, locking

I use in project Striped locks from GUAVA for synchronizing input data for   every unique identifier of process, it provides right order of data for next processing this data.

```
Striped<Lock> locks = Striped.lazyWeakLock(10);
public void put(String id, String data) {
    Lock lock = locks.get(id);
    lock.lock()
    try {
     // process data
    } finally {
       lock.unlock()
    }
}
```

This code works good, provides right order of data.
But I want to get global lock (exclusive access) to current object for modification some data. So i want to stop getting locks for all unique id until I modify data.

Possible solutions:

1. I can use ReasWriteLock before getting striped lock. (read - for "locks.get(id)", write - for exclusive access) - Not good solution, extra locking in normal state.
2. I can use one lock for all, but it will slow down application
3. Global lock

Example:

```
if (locked) {
    global.lock()
    global.unlock()
    Lock lock = locks.get(id);
    ...
} else {
    Lock lock = locks.get(id);
    if (locked){
       ...
    }
    lock.lock();
}

void extraLock(){
   global.lock();
   locked = true;
   // modify data
   locked = false;
   global.unlock()
}
```

I think solution with global lock looks not good(flags, lock, double check and etc)

Question:
Can you advice any solution that can help me to solve this problem?
Or Can you tell some idea?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need exclusive access to the entire data structure for write while using striped locks? There may be several solutions for sure, but can you provide more details on the problem you are trying to solve?